# How to set track_total_hits in Elasticsearch using Laravel Scout?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I have been using https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver and I am looking to set "track_total_hits" to true so I can get the total results.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-track-total-hits

I am not sure how to get an array value to that point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are using is not implementing the `track_total_hits` (a search on the repo content will confirm that). You can, however, fork the repo and add the functionality yourself if required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to solve it, I created my own implementation to include `track_total_hits` and more…, using callback Closure.

##### 1. Extend `SearchRequestFactory`

```php
use ElasticScoutDriver\Factories\SearchRequestFactory;
use ElasticAdapter\Search\SearchRequest;
use Laravel\Scout\Builder;

class ElasticSearchRequestFactory extends SearchRequestFactory
{
    public function makeFromBuilder(Builder $builder, array $options = []): SearchRequest
    {
        $searchRequest = parent::makeFromBuilder($builder, $options);

        if ($builder->callback) {
            call_user_func($builder->callback, $searchRequest, $builder);
        }

        return $searchRequest;
    }
}
```

##### 2. Register extended SearchRequestFactory in `AppServiceProvider`

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(SearchRequestFactoryInterface::class, ElasticSearchRequestFactory::class, true);
}
```

##### 3. Set values using `SearchRequest`

```php
use ElasticAdapter\Search\SearchRequest;

//... more code

$results = Model::search($query, function(SearchRequest $request) {
    $request->trackTotalHits(true);
    return $request;
})->paginate();

//... more code
```

Documentation and reference:

- [Add a way to do raw searches](https://github.com/babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver/issues/40#issuecomment-1175000729)
- [How to enable track_total_hits=true by default for all queries?](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-enable-track-total-hits-true-by-default-for-all-queries/198220)
- [Track total hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits)
- [How to Set Up a Full-Text Search Using Scout in Laravel](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-full-text-search-using-scout-in-laravel--cms-30702)